# How to dynamically change css class properties inside extjs by class name?

Tags: extjs

Change calendar Panel BackGround color on basis of selecting date from datepicker

In my application i have one datepicker and calendarpanel. I want to change background color(day,month,week view) of calendar panel on select event of datepicker. I have calendar.css file for calendar panel styles.I want to change certain day(get from database on select event) background color in calendar panel and load events of that day.Is any way to change this?Is possible to change css class properties dynamically by using classname.And how to change bgcolor of a particular time slot ( for example,10amt0 12 pm) of calendar panel (not event status color)?.

Comment: please provide some code what you have done ..

Comment: .ext-cal-hd-ad {
    background-color: #fff;/*#A4A4A4*/
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    border-color: #e3e9ff #e3e9ff #e3e9ff #e3e9ff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
} i have to modify this css class background color when selecting a date(public holiday ) from datepicker

Comment: this is just css you have given, canyou provide html and jquery code you wrote for datepicker